# How to prevent the Visual Brush from stretching its content

Tags: wpf

In my project I want to display a small logo on the side of a custom control. Since I have no canvas I thought maybe a Visual Brush would be a good Idea to place the logo in the background.

```
<VisualBrush>
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" Fill="Red" />
    </VisualBrush.Visual>                
</VisualBrush>
```

But the Rectangle I am using right now is not 200x200. It takes the complete available space. Thats not what I want. I also tried a Viewbox and set the stretch property but the result is the same because in the end I don't need a simple Rectangle but a canvas with many path objects as children. A Viewbox supports only one child.

This there any way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set `TileMode`, `Stretch`, `AlignmentX` and `AlignmentY` properties on your `VisualBrush`:

```
<VisualBrush TileMode="None" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Rectangle Height="200" Width="200" Fill="Red"></Rectangle> 
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

Comment: thanks i was missing the TileMode="None" and Stretch="None"

Answer (score 0):

Add Grid and this Set Vertical alligment to Top and Horizontal alignment to Right
Sample code

```
  <VisualBrush x:Key="myVisual">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Height="200" Width="200" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" ></Rectangle> 
            </Grid>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I set the following attribute on the VisualBrush, and the VisualBrush now looks exactly like a MediaElement:

```
Stretch="Uniform"
```